# VS2013 Professional or Premium?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsto

I need to ensure that the version of VS2013 I get allows me to do Office development.  I understand that Premium allows me to do that, but can't seem to work out if Professional also allows me to do that?

Does anyone know where I can get this info?

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs this link makes no mention of office type development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart of Visual Studio features does indicate that VS Professional supports Office 365, Office and SharePoint development.  You can see this bullet point under section named 'Development Platform Support'.

If you are not convinced by the chart you can always download the 90 day trial of VS 2013 Professional to see that it supports Office development.  I think it is one of the options to select during install.